# Find Successive words in Article B available from A

Tags: algorithm

> There are two articles, A and B, which are very large. Get three or more successive words in A and check if they appear in B, and count how many times they appear. For example, if 'book' 'his' and 'her' appear in A, how many times do they appear in B?

I thought about splitting the entire content of B and then checking all 3 words in A with StringToken, but I am not sure about the algorithm efficiency.

Comment: Questions: 1) Do you need to do this just for 2 documents, or for many documents pairwise? 2) Is there an upper bound for the number of successive words you are interested in, or are essentially looking for longest possible matches? 3) Is this for any programming language in particular (you mention `StringToken` which sounds specific)?

Comment: What language are you using? Is this homework?

Comment: Language is Java and yes it is Homework as I googled for some questions and I found this , 1) as of now its limited to 2 Documents  2) No upperbound, longest possible matches will be an upgraded option and better 3) java

Comment: One more question: I don't understand how the example of 'book', 'his' and 'her' matches the description of the problem. Those are three individual words, not 'three successive' words. And what do you mean by 'getting' three or more successive words? Do you want to identify _all_ words that A and B have in common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into what a [Hashtable](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) is, scan your file B for words one by one (you can split if you don't care about memory usage on large files) each word you find into the hashtable (when not found) or increment the number to get of times a word is seen.

Then you just scan. over A, looking for each set of 3 words, with a rolling sliding window. this way you can increase the length of the window later without rewriting anything.

for reference you should really tag homework questions as such.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that you need to scan / parse entire content of B once to reach the results. You just cannot avoid doing that. Read it line by line. For every line, search for the given query terms and their counts in the line. Keep adding the counts generated on per line basis to get the final result.

If you want to do such computation many times on content of B for same/different terms, creating an [Inverted_index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) for B would be best way.